# Google Fonts not working whenever I paste the bootstrap CDN

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I used Google fonts for a landing page I am making, I am also trying to put bootstrap in there. Whenever I paste the bootstrap link in there, all my fonts stop working.
I made sure to paste all links for my css in the proper order and I have also tried copying different links for bootstrap, nothing is working...Can I have some assistance?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Burger</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

    <!-- ^^^ THIS IS THE CDN THAT CAUSES THE ISSUE ^^^ -->

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="homepage">
    <div class="overlay">
    <img src="photo-1571091718767-18b5b1457add.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg1">
</div>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <a href=""><li><i class="fas fa-hamburger logo"></i></li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Choices</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
    <div class="textcont">
        <div class="toptext"><h3>THE BEST BURGERS</h3></div>
        <div class="middletext"><h1>Meals You Can't Resist</h1></div>
        <div class="menubtn">OUR MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foodcont">
    <div class="box"><img src="hamburger.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Cheeseburgers</h2><h4 class="subtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, aut.</h4></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="french-fries.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">French Fries</h2><h4 class="subtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sit, sequi.</h4></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="soda.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Beverages</h2><h4 class="subtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, in!</h4></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="cookie.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Cookies</h2><h4 class="subtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae, nisi?</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="choicesp1">
    <div class="titlesec"><h3 class="redtext">JUICY AND DELICIOUS</h3>
    <h2 class="maintexttitle">Choose and Enjoy</h2><h3 class="subtexttitle">Homemade meals made by great chefs</h3></div>
    <div class="foodcont2">
        <div class="box"><img src="amirali-mirhashemian-sc5sTPMrVfk-unsplash.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Burgers</h2><h4 class="subtext">Cheeseburgers with your choice of toppings and sides</h4></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="eaters-collective-pLKgCsBOiw4-unsplash.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">BBQ Sandwich</h2><h4 class="subtext">BBQ sandwiches with Memphis BBQ and Hot Sauce</h4></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="monika-grabkowska-pHeX8H9WQpY-unsplash.png" alt=""class='veggie'><h2 class="maintext">Healthy Sandwich</h2><h4 class="subtext">Healthy option for Vegans</h4></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="mockup-graphics-nXjvUlE8418-unsplash.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">French Fries</h2><h4 class="subtext">Our main side along with others</h4></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="deepal-tamang-D8XcEUt3Tmc-unsplash.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Beverages</h2><h4 class="subtext">Your choice of soda or other drink</h4></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="ariana-suarez-W1Q6TAotxfY-unsplash.png" alt=""><h2 class="maintext">Desserts</h2><h4 class="subtext">Different types of desserts such as cookies and chocolate cakes</h4></div>
        <div class="menubtn">OUR MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="choicesp2">
    <div class="boxcont">
    <div class="box"><img src="amirali-mirhashemian-sc5sTPMrVfk-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><div class="textcontainer"><div class="maintext1">Standard Cheeseburger</div><div class="subtext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, iure.</div><div class="price">$3.99</div><div class="menubtn">ORDER NOW</div></div></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="chad-montano-gE28aTnlqJA-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><div class="textcontainer"><div class="maintext1">Chicken Wings</div><div class="subtext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, alias.</div><div class="price">$4.99</div><div class="menubtn">ORDER NOW</div></div></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pexels-photomix-company-103566.jpg" alt="smooth"><div class="textcontainer"><div class="maintext1">Strawberry Smoothie</div><div class="subtext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, assumenda!</div><div class="price">$1.99</div><div class="menubtn">ORDER NOW</div></div></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="ayesha-firdaus-E8DznhhRm3k-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><div class="textcontainer"><div class="maintext1">Chocolate Lava Cake</div><div class="subtext1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, in!</div><div class="price">$3.99</div><div class="menubtn">ORDER NOW</div></div></div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.homepage{
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}
.bgimg1{
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    
}
.overlay:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.45;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 55%;
    left: 15%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
}
.navbar li{
    color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.navbar li:hover{
    color: red;
    border-bottom: red solid 3px;
}
.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.homepage .textcont{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 15%;
}
.logo{
    color: red;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}
.homepage .toptext{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
    background-color: red;
}
.homepage .middletext{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 8rem;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.homepage .menubtn{
    background-color: red;
    width:10%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.8em 0.8em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    border: transparent 2px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.homepage .menubtn:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: red solid 2px;
}
.foodcont{
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.foodcont img{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.foodcont .box{
    padding: 3em;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.foodcont2 .maintext{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
.foodcont .subtext{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
.choicesp1{
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border: rgb(247, 247, 247) 40px solid;
    position: relative;
}
.choicesp1 .titlesec{

}
.choicesp1 .redtext{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 43%;
    margin-left: 9em;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 2em;

}
.titlesec{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.titlesec .subtexttitle{
    padding-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.titlesec .maintexttitle{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.choicesp1 .foodcont2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2fr);
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 13rem;
}

.choicesp1 img{
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    
}

.choicesp1 .box .maintext, .subtext{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.choicesp1 .maintext{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.choicesp1 .subtext{
    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.choicesp1 .box{
    background-color: white;
}

.choicesp1 .menubtn{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    width:10%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 93%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 0.8em 0.8em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    border: red 2px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.choicesp1 .menubtn:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.choicesp2{
    height: 160vh;
}
.choicesp2 .boxcont{
    width: 120vw;   
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.choicesp2 img{
    height: 73.8vh;
    width: 50vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.choicesp2 .box:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.55;
    
}

.choicesp2 .box{
    position: relative;
    height: 75vh;
    border: 5px solid white;
}
.choicesp2 .textcontainer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 38%;
    height: 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    transform: translateX(-40%);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.choicesp2 .maintext1{
    font-size: 4rem;
    width: 68%;
}
.choicesp2 .subtext1{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    /* padding: 1em 0em; */
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.choicesp2 .price{
    font-size: 3rem;
    /* padding-bottom: 0.5em; */
}
.choicesp2 .menubtn{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: white 1.8px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.8em;
    width: 32%;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.choicesp2 .menubtn:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please modify your custom CSS `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;`

Comment: Bootstrap has customized several html tags - that might be overriding your expected appearance. Can you pin point to an example?

Comment: Yes. It happens to all the code I have Put a font family of 'Montserrat' on.

Comment: What kind of errors do you have on your layout? Montserrat seems to work fine. See https://codepen.io/nufrankz/pen/vYxyLMz

Comment: I looked at your codepen.. you see where it say "the best burgers"? that isnt supposed to look like that. Before I put bootstrap in my file it was all inline and the font was different..

Answer (score 1):

Move this link to
`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">`

After
`<title>Burger</title>`

and Before
`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous"`

If import the font using preconnect doesn't work then you might want to consider using an import statement in your CSS file

Add this line at the top of your CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');
```

comment out the link tag from the HTML page

Also, I noticed that the custom font is used only on specific parts of the HTML page if that is the case update those lines with `!important` that will stop  those tag from inheriting the fonts from bootstrap